# CSS Sprites with Dynamic Sizing

Tags: css, sprite

I've decided to crate a sprite sheet for my entire site (+-30 images) so I can load 1 image and just reference positions, which reduces image load time and server calls.

My question:
Is it possible to reference an image in the sprite sheet and then size that image to 100% of its parent container?

So For example:

```
#SomeDiv
{
    background: url("/Content/Images/SpriteSheet.png") -125px 0 no-repeat;
    width:100px;
}
```

The width of my div is 100px, but the sprite I want to reference is 20px(for example) - how can I streth the extracted sprite to grow to 100px?

Regards,
Byron Cobb.

Comment: You can't, unless you use `background-size`, but browser support for that is pretty poor at the moment

Comment: That's a CSS3 thing for sure, but would't the image look awful anyway? Unless it's a solid color..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, if you *really* want an answer, sure, why not. See: http://jsfiddle.net/3dsgn/3/

Basically we're working with CSS3 here, so IE support (except 9) is non-existent. You'll also have to use the version with the `-moz-` extension for Firefox 3.6 and below. The technique itself is also somewhat troublesome. You actually have to go and calculate the numbers yourself - percentages won't work, naturally.

```
#sprite-large {

    /* All of these numbers are 2x their normal, 
       though tweaked slightly so that they will look okay */
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    background: url('url/to/your/image.png') -38px -112px;

    -moz-background-size: 448px 368px;
    background-size: 448px 368px;
}
```

Comment: And if you extend compass... this will be automatic on compile :)

Comment: Worked GREAT. Thanks, I was really needing this and I wasn't being able to figure it out by myself. I would just like to recommend also adding this: `-webkit-background-size: 448px 368px;`, since I see that the image rendering is best with browsers that support WebKit

Comment: @Santz I don't think that will be necessary, since both Chrome and Safari has support for the unprefixed property since version 3.0. The unprefixed version is identical and doesn't affect image rendering at all

Comment: Great then, just a comment!