# page hangs when i repeat image 10000 times.. any alternate jquery or javascript solution is needed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP repeating of an image on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547312/php-repeating-of-an-image-on-a-page)

I made a php program to repeat an image on a page in a square box.

The image repeats 100 times in a row and then again 100 times vertically.. that means total 100x100 images are repeating in that square box. The size of one such repeating image is 10x10 pixel.

Now the problem is when the site is to be tested on localhost, the page hangs, when it is tried to be opened, and after it is loaded on scrolling up and down it is slow and hangs a bit.

I used nested for loops to get the image repeated. The code for same is:

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
{for($j=1;$j<=100;$j++)
    {
        echo '<div id="imagebox">';
        echo "<img src='images/image.png'>";
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Guys what could be the problem??

Thanks in advance for any possible solution.

Any alternate programming technique solution like jquery or JS?

using a possible solution i made the id separate for each image by using this code

```
echo '<div id="imagebox"  . "i" . "j">';
```

But this also not helped

Comment: page hangs when because you repeat image 10000 times. use pagination

Comment: `Guys what could be the problem??` The problem is you are loading 1000 images on one page. You do realise that a browser can only make 6 requests to one domain at a time? That means given an average image size of 10Kb * 1000 / say a 1Mbps connection = A DAMN LONG TIME TO DOWNLOAD. If you really need this look into infinite scrolling or paging.

Comment: Please don't repost your question, no matter what reason you think allowed for that. (Also, many people already commented on [your earlier post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547312/php-repeating-of-an-image-on-a-page). I feel it's VERY rude just to repost the same question again.) Thanks.

Comment: It's a interesting question. And maybe he doesn't know how to edit this first question. Maybe...

Comment: @AllysondePaula I know how to edit the question.. but the problem is that.. I m new to this website and dont know if i edit my question whether or not it reaches to new people..

Comment: If that's your motivation, then please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) again, and don't ignore warnings about possible duplicates when typing your (new) question -- both of which try to tell you we do not appreciate duplicate questions on these Q&A sites. Success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try fetching the image dimensions and then setting the height and width of the container div equal to 100 times of height and width of the image (respectively) and then just use CSS background-repeat property to repeat the image on x and y axis. This solution might work as you are trying to repeat a single image.
The HTML:

```
<div id="img"></div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var imgSrc = "http://lorempixel.com/100/100";

$("#img").css({
    background: "url("+imgSrc+") repeat"
});

var newImg = new Image();
newImg.src = imgSrc; 

newImg.onload = function() {
    var imgHeight = newImg.height;
    var imgWidth = newImg.width;

    $("#img").css({
        width : imgWidth*100,
        height: imgHeight*100
    });
}
});
```

Comment: yeah.. this seems to be worth working on.. can u fiddlize that?? That will help a lot.. :)

Comment: yeah.. this seems to be worth working on.. can u fiddlize that?? That will help a lot.. :)

Comment: @swati http://jsfiddle.net/vzX9q/

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try using javascript lazy loading. Where it will only load the images on screen?

For example: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Comment: yeah add js for more lag

Comment: This will make the page not load all images. Only the images on screen. Which may help you not to crash your browser loading all images at a time. It can only be tested. My strange question is. Why so many images on 1 page?

Comment: @Niels thanks for your solution.. but the image is just one only it has to be repeated for so large numbers

Comment: You can't use sprites for that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768739/css-sprites-with-dynamic-sizing/3768997#3768997